# Specifying a query string in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm integrating with a 3rd party library that validates the query string with a hash (requiring that the order of the query string be preserved). Is there a way to pass a query string literal to rspec?

You can do it in TestUnit with

```
@request.env['QUERY_STRING'] = 'this=is&in=order'
post :whatever
```

But when you do that in rspec, the query string is not passed (to be precise, the action finds no parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to really post the data.

```
@request.env['QUERY_STRING'].should eq 'this=is&in=order'
post :whatever, :this => "is", :in => "order"
```